# Does a standard SQS queue really have best-effort ordering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

The [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html) about standard SQS queues states:

> occasionally (...) more than one copy of a message
> might be delivered out of order. Standard queues provide best-effort
> ordering which ensures that messages are generally delivered in the
> same order as they're sent.

I understand that the delivery order is not *guaranteed* for standard queues, but I am only getting them delivered in completely random order. I initially noticed this via the Java SDK, but you can see the same situation in the console as well.

Steps:

1. Send two or more messages to a standard queue, *any interval apart*
2. Receive a message from the queue

With "best-effort ordering which ensures that messages are generally delivered in the same order as they're sent", I would expect at the very least to see earlier messages received first more often than later messages, but I'm getting completely random results.

1. Is it true that best-effort ordering is being applied to standard SQS queues?
2. If so, how do I receive the (best-effort) earliest message?

---

Background:
I am receiving files in S3 every (approximately) 15 minutes, triggering an event to create an SQS message (therefore I can't directly switch to a FIFO queue, because the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-compatibility.html) say they aren't compatible with S3 events).
I don't need a 100% guarantee that reordering by a few seconds won't occur, I simply want to be reasonably confident that each file is processed after the one from 15 minutes earlier, even if they are both in the queue when I receive a message. Surely "best effort" ordering should do this, but what I seem to get is random ordering, which is no good for me.

Comment: It does look from your experiment that they're not doing a good job at that. However, I wonder, have you tried setting `MaxNumberOfMessages` attribute when calling `ReceiveMessage` API to 1 and seeing if that still gives messages in random order?

Comment: Yes, I have been trying with MaxNumberOfMessages=1 (since I only want to process one file at a time)

Comment: If you are only looking at a small number of message, then they might appear more random because messages are coming from multiple servers. If you had a large quantity of messages, they would be mostly in-order because each server would store the messages in-order (except for messages that exceeded their invisibility timeout). For a general idea of how these servers return messages, see: [Basic Amazon SQS architecture - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-architecture.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Interesting... So if there are, say, 6 distributed SQS servers and I have 6 or fewer messages in the queue, I should expect almost completely random ordering? I can see why this could be the case, but I don't think it fits their description of "messages are generally delivered in the same order as they're sent". It sounds more like "messages are delivered in the same general order as they're sent", which is a different thing. With multiple servers competing to respond with different messages, you would almost never get the exact same order, regardless of the queue sizes.